# How do I measure my APM?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know for StarCraft (1st version) there were some utilities that I could use to measure my APM.

Is it possible for SC2? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starcraft 2 has an APM calculator built in.  While you can't view it real-time (during the game) all game replays contain an APM tab that you can use to measure your improvement (or compare it to your opponent)

Comment: Some custom maps do measure and display your APM in realtime. For example the [YABOT](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=128752) build-tester map does this.

Answer (score 0):

APM is a weird measurement because it seems to have different meanings from different sources.  When APM was initially introduced, it was a measurement of how many actions divided by the total time of the match.

Currently, the most accurate way to measure APM in this traditional method would be to use a third party program like [SC2Gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) to review your replays.  SC2Gears also has the ability to divide your APM into Macro APM and Micro APM to get a better idea of where your actions are being spent.

Blizzard's APM measurements have always been off.  Because Ladder matches are run at Faster Speed, in which each minute occurs faster than it does outside the game, about 43 real word seconds for each in game minute.  This skews the number that Blizzard gives as APM, and your actual APM would be about 40% higher.

Also, recently Blizzard changed how the calculation of 'actions' worked.  They have removed redundant actions from the calculation, so each number may be much lower than before the calculation change.

Answer (score 0):

- You can see your APM using the **Starcraft 2 client**, when watching a replay (as mentioned by Aardvark), but not during normal games.
- You can see your APM with some **custom maps** (as mentioned by Wikwocket). E.g. [YABOT](http://www.sc2mapster.com/maps/yabot/) will show an APM counter when the "-a" chat command is used.
- You can measure your APM using a **third party tool** (as mentioned by VOIDHand). E.g. [Sc2gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) can calculate your APM based on replays and can also display live APM information. (Take the usual precautions when installing third party software. Some may compromise the security of your computer, or conflict with the EULA for Starcraft.)
- Some **peripherals** have the ability to give an indication of APM. Razer sells a mouse, a keyboard (as mentioned by bond), and even a headset with [APM lighting](http://www.razerzone.com/sc2/en/apmlighting). I haven't been able to find other examples of other peripherals that give a measure of APM.

VOIDHand brought up the issue of different forms of APM measurement. Starcraft 2 measures APM according to game time (sometimes called Blizzard time), not real time. The Liquipedia entry on [Game Speed](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Game_Speed) has more information on this issue. The short answer is to convert your APM in game time to APM in real time, you just need to multiply your game time APM by approximately 1.38.

Third party tools sometimes measure APM differently (as mentioned by VOIDHand). Details are usually available by the providers of those tools.

According to [this](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=142171): "SC2 outputs APM data to the registry (to interface with the Razer SC2 peripherals)." So the Razer SC2 peripherals should measure APM according to how the game does.

Currently (as of version 1.4.3.21029) there is a bug where EPM and APM values are reversed when viewing a replay. We should expect a fix sometime in a future patch.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 3 ways to measure your APM, dependig if you want real time results or not:

1. Use Starcraft 2 or other 3rd Party Tool to look at your APM after finishing your game.
2. Use some Tool that captures all your Inputs (Mouse / Keyboard) and calculate your APM in real time.
3. Access the Starcraft 2 APM registry entry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Razer/Starcraft2 its called APMValue) with some 3rd Party Tool in real time.

The Razer Products obviously use the 3. option. But there are free alternatives like [APMSound2](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=142171). Use them at your own risk. They are unobtrusive and Blizzard should not be able to detect them, as they do exactly the same as the Razer products, but Blizzard does not officially allow them.

It does not matter how you measure your APM, there is no right or wrong way as long as you always use the same method.

Just one more tip: If you analyze your APM they should go up during fights (peak) and get lower afterwards. During fights you have to Micro *and* Macro so you need more APM. If your APM get lower you are just "watching" your units fight. Try to Micro *or* if you do not know what to do let them fight and go back to Macro.

Answer (score -3):

If you have a [Razer Marauder StarCraft II Official Gaming Keyboard](http://www.razerzone.com/sc2/en), you can view an approximation of your APM rate by looking at the color of your keyboard.

Comment: What about mouse clicks? Throwing down force fields, focus firing, placing multiple buildings and that kind of stuff involves multiple mouse clicks and only one key press.

Comment: According to <a href ="http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=142171">this<a/>:"SC2 outputs APM data to the registry". So it should measure APM according to how the game does